# Can't convert Configatron::Store to String error when value used as parameter to Object.const_get

Tags: ruby, configatron

I recently replaced a home-grown configuration module with Configatron, but I'm unable to get one use case working.

When I attempt to use a configatron value as an argument to Object.const_get like this:

```
def formatter_class
  Object.const_get(configatron.formatter)
end
```

I get the following error:

```
file.rb:10:in `const_get': can't convert Configatron::Store to String 
  (Configatron::Store#to_str gives Configatron::Store) (TypeError)
```

The configatron assignment looks like this (simplified):

```
configatron.formatter = case
                          when condition?
                            'ExportFormat'
                          else
                            'ScreenFormat'
                        end
```

Even if I do `configatron.formatter = 'ScreenFormat'`, I get the same error.

I've tried variations on the `formatter_class` method too. This fails:

```
def formatter_class
  Object.const_get(configatron['formatter'])
end
```

Of course, this succeeds, but won't fulfill my use case:

```
def formatter_class
  Object.const_get('ScreenFormat')
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my issue. Turns out you can call `configatron.whatever` and it will return a `Configatron::Store` if it's not initialized.

I inserted a call to `configatron.has_key? 'formatter'` before accessing the value. When it returned false, I figured out that the error was occurring in a code path where the value hadn't been initialized yet. Once I initialized the value, the error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Happens when .yml config file is missing. Or the key that you are looking for is not there.

Location:
`/config/NAME.yml`